# При реализации алгоритма заливки остаются полосы

Tags: javascript, canvas

Как можно исправить так, чтобы не было полос? Уже всю голову сломала

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
clearlist();
algorythm();

function clearlist() {
  context.strokeStyle = "black";
  context.lineWidth = 5;
  var grd = context.createLinearGradient(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  grd.addColorStop(0, "#abe5d9");
  grd.addColorStop(0.5, "#f5f36b");
  grd.addColorStop(1, "#f7bfbb");
  // Fill with gradient
  context.fillStyle = grd;
  context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(400, 250, 150, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  context.closePath();
  context.stroke();
}

function algorythm() {
  var pixelSet = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  fillBackground(pixelSet, 0, 0);
  context.putImageData(pixelSet, 0, 0);
}

function fillBackground(mass, x, y) {
  var isFugure = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < mass.data.length; i += 4) {
    if (mass.data[i] == 0 && mass.data[i + 1] == 0 && mass.data[i + 2] == 0) {
      if (isFugure == false) isFugure = true;
      else isFugure = false;
      while (mass.data[i] == 0 && mass.data[i + 1] == 0 && mass.data[i + 2] == 0) {
        i += 4;
      }
    }
    if (isFugure == false) {
      mass.data[i] = 255;
      mass.data[i + 1] = 255;
      mass.data[i + 2] = 255;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas width="800" height="500" id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Понимаю, что проблема в том, что состояние isFigure в начале круга не успевает переключаться....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Алгоритм перебора пикселей поменяйте. Например так:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
clearlist();
algorythm();

function clearlist() {
  context.strokeStyle = "black";
  context.lineWidth = 5;
  var grd = context.createLinearGradient(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  grd.addColorStop(0, "#abe5d9");
  grd.addColorStop(0.5, "#f5f36b");
  grd.addColorStop(1, "#f7bfbb");
  // Fill with gradient
  context.fillStyle = grd;
  context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(200, 156, 150, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  context.closePath();
  context.stroke();
}

function algorythm() {
  var pixelSet = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  fillBackground(pixelSet);
  context.putImageData(pixelSet, 0, 0);
}

function fillBackground(mass) {
  // перебор всех строк
  for (var y = 0; y < canvas.height; ++y) {
    // перебор пикселей в строке слева направо
    for (var x = 0; x < canvas.width; ++x) {
      var i = 4 * (x + y * canvas.width);
      if (mass.data[i] < 30 && mass.data[i + 1] < 30 && mass.data[i + 2] < 30) {
        break;
      }
      mass.data[i] = 255;
      mass.data[i + 1] = 255;
      mass.data[i + 2] = 255;      
    }
    // перебор пикселей в строке справа налево
    for (var x2 = canvas.width - 1; x2 > x; --x2) {
      var i = 4 * (x2 + y * canvas.width);
      if (mass.data[i] < 30 && mass.data[i + 1] < 30 && mass.data[i + 2] < 30) {
        break;
      }
      mass.data[i] = 255;
      mass.data[i + 1] = 255;
      mass.data[i + 2] = 255;      
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas width="800" height="500" id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Как вариант)

Comment: Я думала пробежать по пикселям сверху вниз, но запуталась с индексами...

Comment: То есть сначала слева направо, а потом сверху вниз

Comment: @Наталья, нет. Каждая строка - 1. сначала слева до черноты или до конца, если не встретили черноту, 2. потом справа до позиции из пункта 1 или до черноты.

Comment: это я поняла) у меня еще одна идея была, как реализовать, буквально за 15 минут до Вашего ответа появилась